# Elasticsearch:Per shard per node VS Multiple shards per node?

Tags: elasticsearch

Most article tells me,per shard per node is the best practices,But,if my server has more than one hard disk,and es create new index every day,then the usage of the disk will have great difference.

So,if i create multiple shards(the number equals disks number) of a node,then the usage of the disk will balance?

**edit**:

Here is my `es` configuration:

```
path.data: /data1/es1,/data2/es1,/data3/es1
```

Here id the `df -h` shows:

```
/dev/sdb1       733G  291G  405G  42% /data1
/dev/sdc1       733G  244G  453G  35% /data2
/dev/sdd1       733G  116M  696G   1% /data3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still go for a single shard per node AND use multiple disks. Elasticsearch has a config variable called `path.data` which is an array that accepts multiple locations, if you define more than one location (one per disk for example) it will use both disks and will benefit from the increased IOPS.

Comment: Thank you.i edited the content..I find the usage of disk have great difference? Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737023/elasticsearchhow-to-make-a-balance-of-the-usage-of-disk?noredirect=1#comment61059466_36737023,   I am confused..