# Elasticsearch:How to make a balance of the usage of disk?

Tags: elasticsearch

After i update es's version to 2.2.*,i find the usage of the disk has great difference.

Here is my path configuration:

```
path.data: /data1/es1,/data2/es1,/data3/es1
```

And,here is the usage of the disk.

```
/dev/sdb1       733G  291G  405G  42% /data1
/dev/sdc1       733G  244G  453G  35% /data2
/dev/sdd1       733G  116M  696G   1% /data3
```

How to make a balance of the usage?

**EDIT**:
Here is the shards's info

```
flume-2016-04-20 1     p      STARTED  74719153  49.1gb XXX.162 es162-3 
flume-2016-04-20 1     r      STARTED  74718328  49.7gb XXX.199 es199-2 
flume-2016-04-20 10    p      STARTED  74728889  49.7gb XXX.200 es200-2 
flume-2016-04-20 10    r      STARTED  74729801  49.6gb XXX.199 es199-3 
flume-2016-04-20 2     p      STARTED  74721109  49.9gb XXX.199 es199-2 
flume-2016-04-20 2     r      STARTED  74721374  49.4gb XXX.200 es200-3 
flume-2016-04-20 8     p      STARTED  74734507  49.6gb XXX.160 es160-2 
flume-2016-04-20 8     r      STARTED  74734865  56.4gb XXX.160 es160-3 
flume-2016-04-20 3     p      STARTED  74720419    49gb XXX.200 es200-3 
flume-2016-04-20 3     r      STARTED  74719146  49.5gb XXX.201 es201-2 
flume-2016-04-20 5     p      STARTED  74715897  49.6gb XXX.202 es202-3 
flume-2016-04-20 5     r      STARTED  74716306  49.6gb XXX.162 es162-2 
flume-2016-04-20 4     p      STARTED  74721287  58.6gb XXX.201 es201-2 
flume-2016-04-20 4     r      STARTED  74721702  49.1gb XXX.202 es202-3 
flume-2016-04-20 6     p      STARTED  74726413  49.6gb XXX.162 es162-2 
flume-2016-04-20 6     r      STARTED  74727061  49.6gb XXX.202 es202-2 
flume-2016-04-20 9     p      STARTED  74718669  49.6gb XXX.160 es160-3 
flume-2016-04-20 9     r      STARTED  74717816  49.6gb XXX.200 es200-2 
flume-2016-04-20 11    r      STARTED  74726570  49.5gb XXX.160 es160-2 
flume-2016-04-20 11    p      STARTED  74726215  49.6gb XXX.199 es199-3 
flume-2016-04-20 7     r      STARTED  74700592  49.6gb XXX.201 es201-3 
flume-2016-04-20 7     p      STARTED  74700230  58.6gb XXX.202 es202-2 
flume-2016-04-20 0     p      STARTED  74730842  49.3gb XXX.201 es201-3 
flume-2016-04-20 0     r      STARTED  74730102  55.3gb XXX.162 es162-3
```

And here are the current usage of disk(all nodes have the same usage of disk)

```
/dev/sdb1       733G  201G  495G  29% /data1
/dev/sdc1       733G  294G  402G  43% /data2
/dev/sdd1       733G  291G  406G  42% /data3
```

Comment: What's the output of `GET /_cat/shards?v`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan,Thank you,i edited the content.

Comment: and which node has the three data paths?

Comment: @AndreiStefan,All nodes have three data paths.I have 3 index,here are just one index's shard info.

Comment: And the one you asked about in the post?

Comment: The one i asked is not in the post.it is yesterday's usage.

Comment: Looks like ES rebalanced the shards itself. Then why the question?

Comment: @AndreiStefan,%43,%29,%42 are also have great difference.

Comment: Your shards are too large imo and I'd recreate the index with more shards. Also, the shards' files are all allocated on one path only and not spread on all paths. And ES will not try to balance the files between paths.

Comment: Surely? other one tells me:if you define more than one location (one per disk for example) it will use both disks and will benefit from the increased IOPS...

Comment: When it decides to allocate a new shard to a node with multiple paths it will put it on the path with the most free space. But it will not move one shard from one path and put it on another path. The rebalancing happens between nodes and not between data paths.

Comment: @AndreiStefan,How i to make the disks's usage are almost equal..

Comment: You can't control this process.